# JS Discord Bot Find out how many roles there are

Tags: discord.js

I want to know the total number of roles on the servers where my bot is located.
How can I do? V11. thanks in advance

[İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZV0J.png)

Answer (score 1):

Discord now doesn't support v11. Please update to v12. And in v12, you can get the number of roles in the guild by getting the guild Object, and then doing `<Guild>.roles.cache.size`, would return the count.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
message.guild.roles.forEach(role => console.log(role.name, role.id))
```